# How to cite a website using apa style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, apacite

I have this tex file and I want to make a citation in apastyle,

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn} %% tables cols aligned at decimal point
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setstretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{psfrag}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{url}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\nocite{*} 
%opening
\title{Drug Business}
\author{Andre Resius}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\section{Introduction}


by drugs abuse\cite{dandm}. 



\section{Conclusions}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

I want to cite a website but I am getting the same error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: paper.aux
I couldn't open style file apacite.bst
---line 3 of file paper.aux
: \bibstyle{apacite
:                  }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file paper.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Also this is the bib file reference

```
@Misc{dandm,
title = {Deaths and Mortality},
howpublished =  {\url{https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nvsr/nvsr65/nvsr65\_04.pdf}},
note = {Accessed: 2014-06-30}
}
```

I installed manually the apacite package but still is not working. 
If some one can help me with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you recompile after (a) loading the `url` package as well and (b) changing `\bibliography{mybib.bib}` to `\bibliography{mybib}`?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with `biblatex`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{url}
\title{Drug Business}
\author{Andre Resius}
\date{}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\addbibresource{apabib.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

by drugs abuse \cite{dandm}.

\section{Conclusions}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note I changed the type of the url references to `@online`, with dedicated fields `title`, `url` and `urldate`.

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@Online{dandm,
  title  = {Deaths and Mortality},
  url    = {https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nvsr/nvsr65/nvsr65\_04.pdf},
  urldate  = {2014-06-30}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's the best solution I have found for biblatex + APA style.